# XenServer 7.1.0 PXE installation

Tags: networking, xenserver, pxe-boot

As my IBM Blade Center H has known difficulties with booting HS22 Blades from CDROM the best option for me is installation via network. So I'm trying to set up a PXE boot of the XenServer 7.1.0 installation.
I'm following [Citrix Installation Guide](https://docs.citrix.com/content/dam/docs/en-us/xenserver/xenserver-7-0/downloads/xenserver-7-0-installation-guide.pdf) Appendix C on pages 37ff.

My Blade is booting to a grub console, but not loading the install system. So i guess tftp and dhcp are working fine.

On page 38 the Installation guides says:

> Configuring your TFTP Server for UEFI boot
>
> To configure your TFTP server for UEFI boot:
>
> 1. In the  /tftpboot  directory, create a new directory called  EFI/xenserver.
> 2. Configure your DHCP server to provide  /EFI/xenserver/grubx64.efi  as the boot file.
> 3. Create  grub.cfg  file. For example:

```
     menuentry "XenServer Install (serial)" {
         multiboot2 /EFI/xenserver/xen.gz dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M watchdog dom0_max_vcpus=4 com1=115200,8n1 console=com1,vga
         module2 /EFI/xenserver/vmlinuz console=hvc0
         module2 /EFI/xenserver/install.img }
```

> 4. Copy  grub.cfg  file to  /tftpboot/EFI/xenserver  directory on the TFTP server.
> 5. From  the  XenServer  installation  media,  copy  the  files   grubx64.efi ,   install.img   (from  the root directory),  vmlinuz 
>      and  xen.gz  (from the  /boot  directory) to the new  /tftpboot/EFI/
>      xenserver  directory on the TFTP server. Note: The following examples
>      show how to configure the installer to run on the physical console,
>      tty0. To use a different default, ensure that the console you want to
>      use is the leftmost.

OK, as there is no grubx64.efi file in the ISO root I took the one from /EFI/xenserver.

And then without anything else follows this piece of config. I don't know what to do with it, so maybe my problem is coming from this:

```
> default xenserver 
> label xenserver
> kernel mboot.c32  append /tftpboot/EFI/xenserver/xen.gz
> dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M watchdog dom0_max_vcpus=4 com1=115200,8n1 \ 
> console=com1,vga --- /tftpboot/EFI/xenserver/vmlinuz \  console=hvc0
> console=tty0 \
> --- /tftpboot/EFI/xenserver/install.img
```

Comment: boot via an usb stick?

Comment: The whole Media Tray is not working,  so USB not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a real solution, but:

For some reason the `root` variable in grub is not set, and so grub doesn't find the config file.

My workaround ist to manually set the variable in grub console and load the config

```
set root=(tftp,192.168.xxx)
configfile /EFI/xenserver/grub.cfg
```

Also the grub.cfg needs to be adopted to see the installer on the local Screen:

```
menuentry "XenServer Install (serial)" {
   multiboot2 /EFI/xenserver/xen.gz dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M watchdog dom0_max_vcpus=4 com1=115200,8n1 console=com1,vga
   module2 /EFI/xenserver/vmlinuz console=hvc0 console=tty0
   module2 /EFI/xenserver/install.img }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify your config to something similar - this is using IPXE.
I found [this article from Citrix](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116021) which showed using a ram disk as root. I am a noob when it comes to pxe and ipxe booting and this was the working config for me in the end. I basically saw that the **module** section in IPXE relates to the **---** in pxelinux. Seems like you could set the root in the vmlinuz section of your pxelinux.cfg.

```
:xen
kernel ${base}/XenServer-7.4/boot/xen dom0_max_vcpus=1 dom0_mem=max:1G com1=115200,8n1 console=com1,vga
module ${base}/XenServer-7.4/boot/vmlinuz ramdisk_size=100000 root=dev/ram0 console=hvc0 console=tty0
module  ${base}/XenServer-7.4/install.img
boot || goto failed
goto menu
```